# Python Remove word in element of list

Tags: python, list

I have a  python list like this:

```
['photo_1.jpg', 'photo_10.jpg', 'photo_100.jpg' ]
```

and now I want to remove `.jpg` from every element in the list and become

```
['photo_1', 'photo_10', 'photo_100' ]
```

I have try

```
for x in list:
    x.replace('.jpg', '')
```

But it doesn't work. Could anyone help me. Thanks!

Comment: @ChristianDean I doubt that'll work for them (given how they disregard the results of expressions). And remember the instruction to "Avoid answering questions in comments".

Comment: @KellyBundy, Not sure what you mean? If they use a list comprehension, they're no longer ignoring the result of the expression, they're using it. And fair enough, give the current state of the StackExchange administration, I find it hard to find the motivation to write out full answers.

Comment: @ChristianDean I mean they might very well ignore the result of the list comprehension, too.

Comment: I think the main thing before going further is to avoid using `list` as a variable

Comment: `.replace` creates a new string, which you don't do anything with.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, by every means, you need to prevent using `list` as a variable because `list` is already a built-in function in Python. Using it as a variable will eventually cause you more problems in your later coding.

On the other hand, the only thing you need is to make sure you append it into a new variable if you are not doing list comprehension.

```
newlist = []
for x in list_:
    newlist.append(x.replace('.jpg', ''))
    

newlist
Out[456]: ['photo_1', 'photo_10', 'photo_100']
```

Or a more complicated way, that is using slicing in your string.

```
newlist = []
for x in list_:
    newlist.append(x[:-4])
```